# UISegmentedControl with multiple row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I need a UISegmentedControl with 2 row, I could not implement it. 
I dont want to use 2 different UISegmentedControl. Are there any solution to this problem? How to implement UISegmentedControl with two rows?

Comment: Create a custom view with 2 segmented controls and just tie their state together. When you get the action from the user, set the index of the other one, giving the illusion its 1 control?

Comment: Creating a Segmented control your self is so easy, you really don't need to rely on the one provided by the iOS.

Answer (score 1):

'UISegmentedControl' does not support multiple rows. If you need it you'll have to build it yourself or find a third party library that offers it.

As Helium suggests in his/her comment, you could create a custom control that internally manages 2 or more segmented controls and handles changing states between them.

Truth be told a segmented control is not that complicated. It wouldn't be that hard to create a custom 2D segmented control. If this is a key need then you might want to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you will need to have an IBAction and IBOutlet on each of your segmented control.

Code the IBAction such that clicking on one of the segmented control will set the IBOutlet's selectedSegmentIndex of the other segmented controls(which are not selected) to UISegmentedControlNoSegment. This creates the illusion that the segmented controls are linked.

Then getting the correct info of which segmented control value is selected is simply gathering all the index of the segmented control into one constant.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment1: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var segment2: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var segment3: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func FirstSecond(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment2.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment3.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
}
@IBAction func ThirdFourth(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment3.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
}
@IBAction func FifthSixth(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment2.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
}
let segmentvalue = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth"]
@IBAction func FirstSecond(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment2.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment3.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    let valueINeed = segmentvalue[segment1.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
@IBAction func ThirdFourth(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment3.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    let valueINeed = segmentvalue[segment2.selectedSegmentIndex + 2]
}
@IBAction func FifthSixth(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    segment2.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    let valueINeed = segmentvalue[segment3.selectedSegmentIndex + 4]
}
```

Full Details availabe [here: multi row segemented control in swift](https://yarnthen.github.io/yarnthencohosking/how%20to/2017/10/20/multi-row-segemented-control-xcode-swift.html)

Comment: Please post the code in your link inside your response, not only as a link.